# Doubly linked list sorting: One of the data display twice and the other one is missing

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am not sure how to display the person who have the same GPA in a descending order. If there are two same GPA, It will display the first person twice and the second person with the same GPA will not displayed.

This is the main class

```
  public class N12 { 

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    N1 myList = new N1();

myList.InsertAt(111,"Broke","Tim","5807404822","CS",3.8,1969,11,12,"New York");
myList.InsertAt(222,"Smith","Tom","5807404822","CS",3.6,1979,3,1,"Dallas");
myList.InsertAt(322,"Cook","John","5807404822","ENG",4.0,1993,4,4,"Boston");   
myList.InsertAt(433,"Keller","Frankin","5807404822","ECON",1.3,1932,6,22,"LA");
myList.InsertAt(213,"Smith","Boris","5807404822","ENG",3.5,1993,5,13,"Austin");

myList.GPADS();
    }
}
```

This is the methods

```
public class N1 {
    private class Node
    {  
        Node next;

        int idNum;
        String lname;
        String fname;
        String tel;
        String major;
        double gpa;
        int year;
        int month;
        int date;
        String home;  

        public Node(int id,String ln,String fn,String t,String m,double g,int y, int mon, int d,String h)
        {   idNum=id;
            lname=ln;
            fname=fn;
            tel= t;
            major = m;
            gpa=g;
            year=y;
            month= mon;
            date= d;
            home=h;
            next = null;

        }
        public Node(int id,String ln,String fn,String t,String m,double g,int y, int mon, int d,String h,Node n)
        {   
            idNum=id;
            lname=ln;
            fname= fn;
            tel=t;
            major = m;
            gpa=g;
            year=y;
            month= mon;
            date= d;
            home=h;
            next = n;

        }
    }

    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    private int length;
    private Node currentPos;
    private double gpalist[]=new double [10000];
    private int idd[]=new int [10000];

    private int yearc[]=new int[10000];
    private int monthc[]=new int[10000];
    private int dayc[]=new int[10000];


    public N1()
    {
        length = 0;
        first = last = currentPos = null;
    }


    public void AddToFirst(int id,String ln,String fn,String t,String m,double g,int y, int mon, int d,String h)
    { 
        Node newNode = new Node(id,ln,fn,t,m,g,y,mon,d,h,first);

        first = newNode;
        length++;
        if(length==1) last = newNode;
    }

    public void AddToLast(int id,String ln,String fn,String t,String m,double g,int y, int mon, int d,String h)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(id,ln,fn,t,m,g,y,mon,d,h);
        if(length==0)
        {
            first=last=newNode;
            length++;
            return;
        }
        last.next = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        length++;
    }


    public void InsertAt(int id,String ln,String fn,String t,String m,double g,int y, int mon, int d,String h)
    {



          gpalist[length]=g;
          idd[length]=id;
           yearc[length]=y;
            monthc[length]=mon;
             dayc[length]=d;
  //System.out.println(length);
        if(id<=0) 
        {
            AddToFirst(id,ln,fn,t,m,g,y,mon,d,h);
            return;
        }
        if(id>=length)
        {
            AddToLast(id,ln,fn,t,m,g,y,mon,d,h);
            return;
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(id,ln,fn,t,m,g,y,mon,d,h);
        Node current = first;
        for(int i=0;i<id-1;i++) current = current.next;
        newNode.next = current.next;
        current.next = newNode;
        length++;



    }




    public  void GPADS()
    { 
            String output="";

        int i;
                int j;
                double value;
        for(i=1;i<gpalist.length;i++)
        {
            value = gpalist[i];
            j = i-1;
            while(j>=0&&gpalist[j]<value) 
            {
                gpalist[j+1] = gpalist[j];
                j--;
            }
            gpalist[j+1] = value;
        }

  System.out.println("This is Descending by Gpa: ");
                  for(i=0;i<gpalist.length;i++)
        {
                    if(gpalist[i]!=0)
                    {
                   ByGPA(gpalist[i]); 

                    }

    }
        }


    public String ByGPA(double gpa)//second method
{      String output="";
        Node current = first;

while(current!=null)
       {

    if(current.gpa==gpa)
    {

            output = output+" "+current.idNum+" "+current.lname+" "+current.fname+" "+current.tel
                    +" "+current.major+" "+current.gpa+" "+current.year+" "+current.month
                            +" "+current.date+" "+current.home;  
          System.out.println(output);
         return null;
        }
    current = current.next;

    }
              return "";
}



}
```

Output (with different GPA):

This is Descending by GPA:

> - 322 Cook John 5807404822 ENG 4.0 1993 4 4 Boston
> - 111 Broke Tim 5807404822 CS 3.8 1969 11 12 New York
> - 222 Smith Tom 5807404822 CS 3.6 1979 3 1 Dallas
> - 213 Smith Boris 5807404822 ENG 3.5 1993 5 13 Austin
> - 433 Keller Frankin 5807404822 ECON 1.3 1932 6 22 LA

If I change Boris GPA to 3.8, it will not display, and Broke will display twice.

Output (with same GPA): This is Descending by GPA:

> - 322 Cook John 5807404822 ENG 4.0 1993 4 4
> - Boston 111 Broke Tim 5807404822 CS 3.8 1969 11 12 New York
> - 111 Broke Tim 5807404822 CS 3.8 1969 11 12 New York
> - 222 Smith Tom 5807404822 CS 3.6 1979 3 1 Dallas
> - 433 Keller Frankin 5807404822 ECON 1.3 1932 6 22 LA

Answer (score 0):

Your code has so many unnecessary complexity, I couldn't also catch the code, because it has very unreadable variable names etc. I strongly recommend you to get this as much as readable.

I think the answer to your question is in the `ByGPA` method.

When it finds the first gpa it prints it, but because of the `return` statement it cannot iterate to the other elements.
You can remove this return statement or reconsider the implementation of your ByGPA method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use arrayList <>, with this you would save you time and code.

Solutin:

```
    public void GPADS() {


        int i;
        int j;
        double value;
        for (i = 1; i < gpalist.length; i++) {
            value = gpalist[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && gpalist[j] < value) {
                gpalist[j + 1] = gpalist[j];
                j--;
            }
            gpalist[j + 1] = value;
        }

        double tmpGpa = 0;
        System.out.println("This is Descending by Gpa: ");
        for (i = 0; i < gpalist.length; i++) {
                                   // If gpalist[i] already been used.
            if (gpalist[i] != 0 && gpalist[i]  != tmpGpa) {
                // tmpGpa
                tmpGpa = ByGPA(gpalist[i]);

            }
        }
    }

    //public String ByGPA(double gpa)
    public double ByGPA(double gpa)//second method
    {
        String output = "";
        Node current = first;

        while (current != null) {

            if (current.gpa == gpa) {

                output =  " " + current.idNum + " " + current.lname + " " + current.fname + " " + current.tel
                        + " " + current.major + " " + current.gpa + " " + current.year + " " + current.month
                        + " " + current.date + " " + current.home;
                System.out.println(output);
                // return null;

            }
            current = current.next;
        }

        return gpa;
    }
```